# Spritekit Swift Terminating Error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, runtime-error

I am trying to make a new app in sprite kit with a random colored background, and all I have done is set the color of the background and creating a ball in the game but it won't launch first I'll give my code and then the error. Here is my code so far.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

struct PhysicsCategory {
static let None      :UInt32 = 0
static let All       :UInt32 = UInt32.max
static let Triangle  :UInt32 = 0b1   //body1
static let Circle    : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
 }

var screenWidth: CGFloat! = 0

var screenHeight: CGFloat! = 0


var circle: SKShapeNode! = SKShapeNode()
var bgColor:SKColor!
var arrayOfColors: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
var backgroundNode: SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    // Create the ball
    if screenWidth == 1024{
        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 22)
    }else if screenWidth == 568 || screenWidth == 480{
        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 11)
    }else{
        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    }

    circle.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    circle.alpha = 0
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.frame.size.width/2)
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    circle.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    circle.position = CGPoint (x: 29.952, y: 346.555)

    self.addChild(circle)

    //pick random color
    let UInt32Count = UInt32(arrayOfColors.count)
    let randomColor = arc4random_uniform(UInt32Count)
    let color: SKColor = arrayOfColors[Int(randomColor)] as SKColor

    //set random color
    let colorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(color, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0)
    backgroundNode.runAction(colorAction)
    backgroundNode.size = CGSize(width: 990, height: 640)

    }


 }
```

That is the full code so far, and here is the error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x24c8d5f7 0x324ffc77 0x24ba1157 0x341ec 0x346d8 0x27fb9861 0x27fd4023 0x37888 0x379b0 0x28131c8d 0x281319fd 0x281378c7 0x2813531f 0x2819f5c1 0x283915f1 0x28393a49 0x2839e2f9 0x283922eb 0x2b4030c9 0x24c53ffd 0x24c532c1 0x24c51e1b 0x24b9eb31 0x24b9e943 0x28196127 0x28190f21 0x3a2e8 0x3a324 0x32a9baaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared and initialized your empty array:

```
var arrayOfColors: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

And then you are trying accessing the empty array:

```
let color: SKColor = arrayOfColors[Int(randomColor)] as SKColor
```

This will throw an exception as you showed in console:

> '* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   array'

You first need to populate this array before accessing and make sure that when you generate random number, it is not out of array bounds.